Use 192.168.1.x on docker-compose
I'm installing an OpenVPN Docker container using docker-compose and I need to change the IP range from the default 172.17.0.0 to 192.168.1.x.
I tried adding to the /etc/docker/daemon.json file:
{
  "bip": "192.168.1.5/24", 
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.1.5/25", 
  "default-address-pools":[
      { "base":"192.168.2.5/24", "size":28 }
  ]
}

As explained here, but unfortunately, the problem remains.
I also tried modifying the docker-compose file as indicated here, but nothing changed. The range remains 127.17.x.x.
What can I do?
Here is the docker-compose file I used:
name: openvpn
services:
  app:
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    cpu_shares: 90
    command: []
    container_name: OpenVPN
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 15775M
    environment:
      - PGID=1000
      - PUID=1000
    hostname: OpenVPN
    image: openvpn/openvpn-as:latest
    labels:
      icon: https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/openvpn-icon-512x512-nmf6geqm.png
    ports:
      - target: 943
        published: "1943"
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 443
        published: "1443"
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 1194
        published: "1194"
        protocol: udp
    privileged: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /DATA/AppData/openvpn/data
        target: /openvpn
      - type: bind
        source: /DATA/AppData/openvpn/docker
        target: /etc/docker
    x-casaos:
      ports:
        - container: "943"
          description:
            en_us: "Container Port: 943"
        - container: "443"
          description:
            en_us: "Container Port: 443"
        - container: "1194"
          description:
            en_us: "Container Port: 1194"
      volumes:
        - container: /openvpn
          description:
            en_us: "Container Path: /openvpn"
    devices: []
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet:  192.168.0.0/16
x-casaos:
  architectures:
    - amd64
    - arm64
  author: null
  category: Network
  description:
    en_us: OpenVPN is an open-source commercial software that implements virtual
      private network (VPN) techniques to create secure point-to-point or
      site-to-site connections in routed or bridged configurations and remote
      access facilities.
  developer: ""
  hostname: ""
  icon: https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/openvpn-icon-512x512-nmf6geqm.png
  index: /admin
  is_uncontrolled: false
  main: app
  port_map: "1943"
  scheme: https
  store_app_id: openvpn
  tagline:
    en_us: OpenVPN is an open-source commercial software that implements virtual
      private network (VPN).
  thumbnail: ""
  title:
    custom: ""
    en_us: OpenVPN


I dont see a reason why? everything can be done by either nat or routing?

@djdomi I'm having problems with DNS as I added the subnet to rooting but the normal connection to the internet via safari doesn't work (via chrome and ping 8.8.8.8 yes) and I have to replace "Have clients use the same DNS servers as the access server host" with "Do not alter client DNS server settings" to make it work but at that point TunnelBrick gives me warnings. So to solve it completely I wanted to change the IPs. So I can use the DNS that I set manually  in the client without problems

I dont think that you asking a Business environmental or related infrastructure question. The ip does not matter aslong nat is involved or the routing is probably set up. what has been done until now, to verify that the docker has internet access and has a working dns resolution?
